# Newbie Using Cygwin--vagrant SSH = 'ssh' executable not found

Tags: django, ssh, vagrant

Newbie trying to get into Django for the first time.  Using Cygwin, after vagrant up, I run vagrant ssh, and I get: 'ssh' executable not found i any directories in the %PATH% variable. Is a SSH client installed? Try installing Cygwin, MinGW or Git, all of which contain an SSH client. Or use the PuTTY SSH client with the following, blah blah blah.

I've been at this for over a week now. I have tried PUTTY several times and keep running into these same errors.

It tells me right there in the error I get while using Cygwin to try running it on Cygwin. Unbelievable. Any guesses how I can fix this? I would be forever in debt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this link:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/uw.cs.cs241/rxki2byDWpA

Which was back from 2008, they say that Cygwin doesn't come with SSH installed, so you should try installing OpenSSH on Cygwin. If it is already installed, then this thread:

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-01/msg00170.html

Which is from 2012, says that the PATH may be wrong.

Try each solution in order, and if none work, come back and tell me what the error is.

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't find that info anywhere else.  You were right, it didn't come with SSH.  The first solution solved it.

Comment: You should then mark my answer as the chosen answer, considering the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

During Cygwin install I couldn't find the ssh options - I was trying to search for them. The [image from step #9 helped](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC152) me out.